# How to loop the potential?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am currently working on a molecular dynamics simulation of polymers in solution, this is one of the subroutines which calculates the potential energy of the system and the force exerted on each monomer.

```
function eval_force()
% eval_force.m IS USED FOR EVALUATING FORCE


% THE STRATEGY USUALLY ADOPTED FOR A LENNARD-JONES OR AS A MATTER OF FACT
% ANY PAIR-WISE INTERACTING SYSTEM IS AS FOLLOWS:
% 1. EVALUATE THE DISTANCE BETWEEN TWO PAIRS OF ATOMS
% 2. ENSURE THAT MINIMUM IMAGE CONVENTION (MIC) IS FOLLOWED
% 3. IF THE DISTANCE OBTAINED THROUGH MIC IS GREATER THAN THE CUT OFF
% DISTANCE MOVE TO NEXT PAIR
% 4. ELSE EVALUATE POTENTIAL ENERGY AND CALCULATE FORCE COMPONENTS
% 5. F(i,j) = -F(j,i)

global MASS KB TEMPERATURE NUM_ATOMS LENGTH TSTEP;
global EPS SIG R_CUT GAMMA POT_E;
global POSITION VELOCITY FORCE STO;

dr = zeros(3,1);
drh = zeros(3,1);
FORCE(:) = 0.0;
POT_E = 0.0;

for ( i=1:NUM_ATOMS )
    for ( j=i+1:NUM_ATOMS )

        dist2 = 0.0; % VARIABLE dist2 STORES DISTANCE BETWEEN PAIR (i,j)

        % FIRST FIND OUT THE DIFFERENCE IN X,Y AND Z COORDINATES
        % VARIABLE dr IS USED FOR THIS PURPOSE
        for(k = 1:3)
            dr(k) = POSITION(i,k) - POSITION(j,k);

            % THESE STEPS ENSURE MINIMUM IMAGE CONVENTION IS FOLLOWED
            if(dr(k) > LENGTH/2.0)
                dr(k) = dr(k) - LENGTH;
            end
            if(dr(k) < -LENGTH/2.0)
                dr(k) = dr(k) + LENGTH;
            end
            % MINIMUM IMAGE CONVENTION ENDS HERE

            dist2 = dist2 + dr(k)*dr(k); % dist2 IS BASED UPON MIC
        end

        if(dist2 <= R_CUT*R_CUT) % IF THE CUT OFF CRITERIA IS SATISFIED
            dist2i = power(SIG,2)/dist2;
            dist6i = power(dist2i,3);
            dist12i = power(dist6i,2);
            POT_E = POT_E + EPS * (dist12i - 2*dist6i) + 33.34 * EPS *     power(sqrt(dist2) - SIG,2)/(2 * power(SIG,2)); % STORES THE POTENTIAL ENERGY

            Ff = 12.0 * EPS * (dist12i-dist6i) - 33.34 * EPS * (sqrt(dist2) - SIG)/(dist2i * sqrt(dist2) * power(SIG,2));
            Ff = Ff * dist2i;

            for(k = 1:3)
                FORCE(i,k) = FORCE(i,k) + Ff*dr(k)- GAMMA*VELOCITY(i,k);
                FORCE(j,k) = FORCE(j,k) - Ff*dr(k)- GAMMA*VELOCITY(j,k);
            end
        end
   end
end

end
```

How can I make a loop for the "33.34 * EPS * power(sqrt(dist2) - SIG,2)/(2 * power(SIG,2))" part under POT_E which is the harmonic potential, so it only evaluates the distance between atoms for the nearest ones (for j=i+1 to 4).

Comment: You do know that in a low-level language (like fortran, which this code was originally intended to be, at least seemingly) you'd get a huge speed-up compared to matlab? For any serious application I suggest migrating to a lower-level language once the prototyping and proof-of-concept are done.

Answer (score 0):

After having a quick look at your code, I'd suggest the following ideas:

- Calculate all-to-all distances at once using `pdist` and store it in a matrix, say `AllDist`.
- The conditions based on `LENGTH` can be applied directly on `AllDist`.
- Since you need to find four nearest neighbors, you need to have a single loop iterating through the rows (or columns) of `AllDist`, which sorts the current row (or column) and gives you four nearest neighbors. Note that for each atom, you'd get `0` as the nearest distance as this is the "self-distance". Ignore this.
- If you have access to Matlab's Parallel Computing Toolbox, try to use it (`parfor`) where appropriate to accelerate your simulation.